# Getting category based on production shift

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping

I have this query

```
    with cte as(
    SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seq ORDER BY date_time) rn1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seq, output > 0
                                 ORDER BY date_time) rn2
    FROM myTable
;

select
seq,
date_time::date,
MIN(date_time) AS MinDatetime,
MAX(date_time) AS MaxDatetime,
SUM(output) AS sum_output
FROM cte cte
GROUP by
seq,
date_time::date ,
cntpr > 0,
rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY
seq,
MIN(date_time);
```

here's the result:

[image]

what I would like to do is to join my result to this master table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfV7c.png)
[image]

and the expected result will be MinDatetime and MaxDatetime among my master table's start and end shift to show the shift information, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtUmN.png)

Any help would be very appreciated.. thank you!

Comment: In your expected results, how do you get times like 7:15, 7:30, 10:15, 10:30, etc? Those times don't look like anything from your results or master table at all

Comment: Please replace images with editable text. Add script for create table, add sample data and expected result.

Comment: @stifin hello, the column time in my expected results is just an example.. say the mindatetime 7:15 and maxdatetime 7:30.. 7:15 and 7:30 is in time range of shift 1..

Comment: What is the type of start shift and end shift, respectively? Can you create a SQL Fiddle so we could play around with it?

Comment: so your example expected results are **not** expected results from your result and master tables?

Comment: @stifin i think there was a misunderstanding, my bad, i edited the expected result, you can check it out if you will.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
select seq, shift, start_shift, end_shift, MinDateTime, MaxDateTime 
from
(
select
seq,
MIN(date_time) AS MinDatetime,
MAX(date_time) AS MaxDatetime,
SUM(output) AS sum_output
FROM cte cte
GROUP by
seq
ORDER BY
seq,
MIN(date_time::date)) t
join mstr
on 
CASE
    WHEN start_shift < end_shift THEN (MinDateTime::time between start_shift and end_shift) OR (MaxDateTime::time between start_shift and end_shift)
    ELSE (MinDateTime::time >= start_shift) OR
         (MaxDateTime::time >= start_shift) OR
         (MinDateTime::time <= end_shift) OR
         (MaxDateTime::time <= end_shift)
END
ORDER BY seq;
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/4208

Explanation: I get the groups, join them with master table on interval matching.